# Inspite of set network-mode 3G type, getting 2G connection with mobile broadband

Tags: networking, bug-reporting, mobile-broadband, 3g

I have set 3G type at mobile-broadband setting:

[image: screen1]

**But I still getting 2G (EDGE) type *very-slow* connection**:

[image: screen2]

Also **3G network available** as following:
[image: screen]

How to solve this and **get only 3G (HSPA/WCDMA) instead of EDGE** connection? (Because There is BSNL-3G **available in my area** and **work correctly** on android-phone & windows)

I've tried after replugging and restarting but not solved.

Comment: Just because you set it as 3G doesn't mean that you'll get a 3G conection all the time. Are you sure you get 3G where you are? Try geting a 3G signal in another area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall `network-manager` & `modem-manager-gui` with 2G connection.(though it is slow)

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install network-manager
sudo apt-get --reinstall install modem-manager-gui
```

(Optional)Then install the necessary packages for `network-manager` to work.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager dpkg dbus dnsmasq-base iproute iputils-arping isc-dhcp-client libc6 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libglib2.0-0 libgudev-1.0-0 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 lsb-base udev upstart-job wpasupplicant
```

Comment: How is reinstalling the underlying networking framework gonna help them get 3G signal?  (your solution sounds fishy to me)

Comment: @123456 I reinstalled `network-manager` and `modem-manager-gui` and after restarting, **now getting 3G (HSPA) connection!**. (I not needed to install any extra package for `network-manager`) How this helped me?

Comment: Exactly don't know. I had the same problem some time ago. It solved by after reinstalling and installing above packages.